# Environment Variable for Username

Tags: scripts

What is the Linux equivalent of %username%?

I need to run a script on multiple Linux boxes every few days. I made a .sh file, and it works fine. The script deletes some files at a certain path. Problem is that the path includes the username (no, not in /home), which is different on each machine.

For now, I simply modified the script on each machine to match the username used there. But I want to have a script that will work, without needing to modify it.

So: does Linux have such functions? Duh, I'm sure it does, you noob....

Comment: That depends, what does `%username%` mean? I guess it's some sort of Windows thing, but don't assume we'll know what it is. We're Linux people here, and most of us know very little about Windows. Please [edit] your question and explain what you need.

Comment: I've edited the title for this (pending peer review).  You're not asking about a "wildcard"; %username% is a Windows _environment_variable_, and you're asking about the Linux equivalent, (which is also an environment variable).

Comment: It'd be marvellous if you could accept whichever answer you found most helpful, to round of the Q&A format nicely.

Comment: @Arronical true. Honestly, I didn't read any of the other answers and comments. I feel that everything added after your answer fails to realize the background to my question. Once the flood started, I didn't care about this thread anymore. I rarely interact with any of the SE sites (posts, answers or comments). About 90% of the times that I did, I hated what followed and disliked SE a little more. I like to read posts and discussions, but there's a certain square-headedness to SE overall, I feel. There are plenty of other highly professional forums that I like (Spiceworks, LinkedIn groups).

Comment: @Arronical I'm not trying to say that SE should change things. Evidently this system works great.

Comment: @Arronical when the comments started getting irrelevant, I wanted to delete the post. Unfortunately, that option doesn't exist here.

Comment: SE is definitely a very different format to a forum, it's one that I get along well with, as I like that any answers given are vetted by others through the voting process. Horses for courses really. It's certainly not perfect. In this case it's worth taking Keith Thompson's answer into account if you're running this script as a cron job. Cron doesn't use the same environment as an interactive session, or a script launched form a user's command line, so $USER won't necessarily work in that case.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The Linux version environment variable to refer to the current user is `USER`.

To get the output you'd like to see use `$USER` in your command:

```
echo $USER
```

And to use it in another string such as a path:

```
/path/with/$USER/in/it
```

Will expand the username within the string. Though you should protect variable expansions with curly braces when a variable is directly next to other characters. It's not so important in this example as the USER variable is bounded by non-alphanumeric characters, but would be important in the following case:

```
/path/to/${USER}directory
```

(Thanks to ByteCommander for the tip in comments)

Another useful one to know is `$HOME` for the user's home directory.

Answer (score 12):

```
$USER
```

will change it into your username.

Example

```
rinzwind@schijfwereld:~$ echo $USER
rinzwind
```

---

There are more...

```
~$ cd /tmp
:/tmp$ echo $HOME
/home/rinzwind
:/tmp$ echo $PWD
/tmp
$ echo $HOSTNAME
schijfwereld
```

To list the current values of all environment variables:

```
env
```

---

Keep in mind that variable names are case-sensitive

---

To expand on this. You can create your own too:

```
export var=value
```

will create $var with value.

```
$ export var=1111
rinzwind@schijfwereld:~$ echo $var
1111
```

Comment: Case sensitivity is a very good point to raise with someone coming from an MS background.

Comment: Note that `export` is only necessary if you want child processes to also see the variable and its value. If it's only being used in the current process a simple assignment is sufficient. Also, you should quote variables when they are evaluated: `echo "$var"`

Answer (score 9):

There might be a caveat if you plan to read the `$USER` environment variable in a command starting with `sudo`.

Bash variable expansion takes place before executing `sudo` to switch users, that means the `$USER` variable gets read from the current environment before `sudo` switches to root.

```
$ echo $USER
bytecommander

$ sudo echo $USER
bytecommander
```

If this is not intended and you require a method that will return the name of the user as whom it really runs (normally "root"), you have at least three options to achieve that:

- Run a `bash` interpreter as root and pass it the command which contains `$USER`. You must make sure that the command is enclosed with single quotes to prevent the current Bash interpreter from doing the variable expansion:

  ```
  sudo bash -c 'echo $USER'
  ```
- Use a command output instead of the `$USER` environment variable.

  There are mainly two commands which would be useful here, `whoami` and `id -un`:

  ```
  $ whoami
  bytecommander

  $ sudo whoami
  root

  $ id -un
  bytecommander

  $ sudo id -un
  root
  ```

  More information about those commands can be found by typing `man whoami` and `man id`.

You can use these commands like a variable and embed them into a string (e.g. a directory path) like this, using Bash's command substitution syntax. Here are two examples which `cd` into a directory named after the current user:

```
cd /path/to/$(whoami)folder
cd /path/to/$(id -un)folder
```

Comment: Is `whoami` the exact same as `id -un`?

Comment: the end result is :P

Comment: `sudo echo $USER` doesn't display `bytecommander` because `sudo` preserves environment variables -- in fact, `sudo` discards most environment variables that it has not been explicitly configured to keep. The reason `sudo echo $USER` displays `bytecommander` is that the variable substitution is performed by the shell before the result is passed to `sudo`; it's equivalent to `sudo echo bytecommander` in your case. Try `sudo sh -c 'echo $USER'` instead.

Comment: @StuartOlsen Thank you very much for correcting my mistake, you're of course right. I observed this incorrectly. Would you mind reviewing my updated and corrected answer again?

Answer (score 5):

As the other answers say, `$USER` is *usually* set to the name of the current user account.

But at least on my system (Ubuntu 14.04) the `$USER` environment variable is *not* set for cron jobs. Instead, you can use `$LOGNAME` ([POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html#tag_08_03)), which *is* part of the environment for cron jobs.

According to the `environ(7)` man page (type `man 7 environ` or `man environ.7` to read it), `$USER` is used by BSD-derived programs and `$LOGNAME` is used by System-V-derived programs. They should have the same value if they're both set. The existence of both is an historical accident.  (There could be cases where `$USER` is set and `$LOGNAME` isn't, but I don't know of any.)

The `environ` man page also documents a number of other common environment variables. (It doesn't document *all* environment variables because it would be impossible to do so.)