# Ubuntu Software doesn't open in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: package-management, 20.04, gnome-software

If i click on Ubuntu Software, it doesn't open. I have a fresh install of Ubuntu 20.04. I tried try to upgrade all packages, but it doesn't fix this problem.

If I try to run `killall software-center` there is no process with this name, and `software-center` returns `command not found`. If I try to reinstall it with apt I have these results:

```
$ sudo apt-get --purge --reinstall install software-center
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package oracle-java8-installer is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
E: Package 'software-center' has no installation candidate
```

Comment: Related: [Ubuntu Software Center (“Software” program) and “Snap Store” missing on fresh Ubuntu 20.04 install (& can't install *.deb files from GUI file manager)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1265806/ubuntu-software-center-software-program-and-snap-store-missing-on-fresh-ub/1265807#1265807)

Answer (score 55, accepted):

The Ubuntu Software Center (*software-center*) has been upgraded to GNOME Software (*gnome-software*) in Ubuntu 16.04 and later. The software app has also been renamed to Software in Ubuntu 20.04 and later. In Ubuntu 22.04 and later the software app has been renamed again to Ubuntu Software and clicking the Ubuntu Software icon launches the Snap Store.

If the Software app doesn't open run the following commands:

```
sudo apt clean # clean list of cached packages so Ubuntu Software can read them
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt autoremove gnome-software && sudo apt install gnome-software
```

Comment: thanks a lot, now i've software center working

Comment: Didn't work for me. Still the same problem.

Comment: However launching from the terminal works with the command `gnome-software`. Another problem is that the gnome-software shows around 500 MB of updates. While `sudo apt update` tells me that all the packages are up to date.

Comment: Make another desktop launcher and you can launch it from the Dash by clicking it. [How can I create launchers on my desktop?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/64222/). If you can't update that's a package management issue. You should ask a separate question about that.

Comment: Following the steps and restart my computer solved the issue. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Ubuntu Software is a fork of GNOME Software, packaged as a snap, and installed by default.  GNOME Software is also available in the archives, packaged as a traditional apt package.  Your instructions don't fix Ubuntu Software, they install GNOME Software alongside it.

Both can be used to manage apt packages.  Only Ubuntu Software can deal with snaps.  Only GNOME Software can deal with Flatpaks (if you apt install the flatpak plugin for it).

Comment: The package that is called Software in 20.04 can be installed by running `sudo apt install gnome-software` and it can and does manage both snap packages and apt packages.

Comment: You might need to reinstall some other pkgs uninstalled on the autoremove step, like the one [from Flatpak](https://www.flatpak.org/setup/Ubuntu/), `gnome-software-plugin-flatpak`

Comment: remember to change the application you open the .deb file with. After the above commands I had 2 software install apps (confusing right !) and when I used the second one it opened it and I was able to install. BTW I am using Ubuntu 22.

Answer (score 32):

What is that doesn't work?

Is that `gnome-software` (see icon below)

[image: screenshot]

(If you hover your mouse over this on your dock/taskbar you get the tooltop `Software`. I didn't have this one docked to my taskbar on a fresh Ubuntu 20 installation.)

or `snap-store`? (see icon below)

[image: screenshot]

(the tooltip for this is `Ubuntu Software`).

To find out more information about why either of the 2 is failing, try to open them from a terminal:

- Open a terminal (<kbd>Ctrl + Alt + t</kbd>`, or` windowsKey`and then search for`terminal`, or click on` show applications`on your dock/taskbar and then search for`terminal`)
- Run them: `gnome-software`. Or `snap-store`.

Then, google again with the new information that you got.

---

A couple of ideas:

- If if `gnome-software` is the one that doesn't work, you may try to follow [karel instructions](https://askubuntu.com/a/1232241/817574):

  ```bsh
  sudo apt clean # clean list of cached packages so Ubuntu Software can read them
  sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
  sudo apt autoremove gnome-software && sudo apt install gnome-software
  ```
- If `snap-store` is the one that is not working, I can tell you what was my problem (maybe you have a similar one). When I tried to run it I got a permission denied error:

  ```
  [...] WARNING: cannot create user data directory: 
  cannot create "/home/<username>/snap/snap-store/454": 
  mkdir /home/<username>/snap/snap-store: permission denied
  ```

this was happening because when I installed a fresh Ubuntu 20, I copied data from a backup of my previous system (CentOS), which had a `snap` directory inside my user's home directory. During the copying process, that directory got copied as owned by the `root` user.

(You can check the permissions, the user owner and the group of that directory with `ls -al ~ | grep snap` and similarly for what's inside with `ls -al ~/snap`)

To solve this I just changed the owner of my `snap` directory (and everything that was inside) with

```bsh
sudo chown <myuser>:<mygroup> -R ~/snap
```

(replace `<myuser>` and `<mygroup>` with whatever are your user and group. E.g. `bob:bob` (or use the [environment variable `$USER`](https://askubuntu.com/a/802737/349837)). Use the ones that appear for almost everything you have inside your home, when running `ls -al ~`. Or check your user and its groups by running `id`).

After that I was able to run `snap-store`.

Comment: Was able to run `gnome-software`.

Answer (score 16):

You can also try

```
sudo snap remove snap-store
sudo snap install snap-store
```

***Remember it will ask for a password with pop-up***

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me on 22.04 as well.

Comment: I can confirm - the best solution for Ubuntu 22.04 - well done

Comment: I had corrupted the snap with a kill command in the wrong moment. Tried what ever is possible, nothing to do. Clicking on the orange icon it will showing something for few seconds in the top bar but no software center window opened. Until I have found this reply. Weird this is not the accepted answer since it really purged the snap GUI and installed again from scratch. I mean the orange icon was removed during this solution process and then after install was placed again in the side bar. +1.000 - With others solutions the orange icon was always there.

Answer (score 7):

Try reinstalling it by using the below command, it worked for me after installing Ubuntu 20.04 today.

```
sudo apt-get --purge --reinstall install gnome-software
```

One more thing, I noticed that the 'Ubuntu Software' in my Dock was not working (it hangs). Even if I search for it under Application it hangs, I had to select 'Software' which has the same exact icon, that one works fine.  Make sure you close Ubuntu Software before you run the command.

Let me know if that works for you. Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

If you are referring to snap-store (the Ubuntu Software application), then I was getting the app failing silently on a brand new 20.04 install.

Typing "snap refresh snap-store" from the command line installed an updated version 467 (was previously 433) and everything worked after that.

Comment: This worked for me on a more or less fresh 20.04 install.

Answer (score 2):

Try using these commands in the terminal. It worked for me!

```
sudo apparmor_parser -r /etc/apparmor.d/*snap-confine*
sudo apparmor_parser -r /var/lib/snapd/apparmor/profiles/snap-confine*
sudo apparmor_parser -r /var/lib/snapd/apparmor/profiles/*
```

Comment: What does this do?

Answer (score 1):

Open terminal and:

`gnome-software`

This worked for me at least on "Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS".

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with snap-store so I installed gnome-software:

```
sudo apt install gnome-software
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to install the candidate version. It worked for me.

First, remove the snap-store. It also removes your Software Center.

```
snap remove snap-store
```

then install the candidate version

```
snap install snap-store --candidate
```

[image]

or, you can use another alternative, Gnome Software

```
sudo apt install gnome-software
```

[image]

source : [Ubuntu : Can't Open Software Center](http://blog.andhiirawan.my.id/ubuntu-tidak-bisa-membuka-software-center/)

Answer (score 0):

The reason it didn't work for me is because I disabled the `snapd.service`. This doesn't prevent ordinary snap-based software from running, but it does make the store non-functional.