# Ubuntu Software Center missing in 20.04

Tags: apt, software-center

I just installed Ubuntu 20.04.  However, I ran into an issue with Ubuntu Software Center not launching so I removed the snap and reinstalled it using the terminal.  But, it was changed to "Snap Store".  I tried installing the regular gnome software center using apt (sudo apt install ubuntu-software), but it is showing up as Gnome Software Center without any Ubuntu branding.

Question:  How do I get the shortcut for Ubuntu Software Center back?  I don't mind if it points to either the snap store or the gnome software center.  I'd just like it to have the ubuntu software center branding.  Thanks!

Comment: It is the same thing. Starting from Ubuntu 16.04 LTS Ubuntu replaced its previous Ubuntu Software Center program with GNOME Software. See the [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNOME_Software).

Comment: *Why* do you want the "Ubuntu branding" when apparently Ubuntu themselves don't want to provide it?

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1265806/ubuntu-software-center-software-program-and-snap-store-missing-on-fresh-ub/1265807#1265807 and https://askubuntu.com/questions/1231932/ubuntu-software-doesnt-open-in-ubuntu-20-04

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Has 'Ubuntu Software' been renamed to 'Snap Store'?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1252134/has-ubuntu-software-been-renamed-to-snap-store)

Answer (score 1):

Same thing happened to my ubuntu 20.04. The software center just went missing and along came out snap store. When I opened snap store, it is very similar with software center and it is doing the same job well. I think it snap store is now the de facto replacement for software center.

Comment: snap store and the previous software center (gnome-software) are not the same, and they don't necessarily do the same thing. Snap store has only snap packages, I believe, whereas gnome-software can have both apt or snap packages.

Answer (score 1):

The below steps worked for me in Ubuntu 20.04

```
sudo apt update

sudo apt install ubuntu-software
```

Then go to Activities to search for the Software Center once the installation has completed.