# Ubuntu Software Doesn't start

Tags: software-center

**Ubuntu 20.04**

When I tried to install `Simplenote` from `Ubuntu software` I faced message error:

`$ snap “package-name” has “install-snap” change in progress`

I'm tried solved this problem:

`$ sudo snap abort NUMBER_ID_PROCESS`

And after that `Ubuntu Software` doesn't start.

What I'm tried:

`$ sudo apt install gnome-software`

[This](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1231932/ubuntu-software-doesnt-open-in-ubuntu-20-04) Didn't work for me.

But it didn't help.

In `terminal` `$ snap-store` show me:

```
snap-store
/home/n199a/snap/snap-store/common/.cache/gio-modules/libdconfsettings.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Failed to load module: /home/n199a/snap/snap-store/common/.cache/gio-modules/libdconfsettings.so
/home/n199a/snap/snap-store/common/.cache/gio-modules/libgiognomeproxy.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Failed to load module: /home/n199a/snap/snap-store/common/.cache/gio-modules/libgiognomeproxy.so
/home/n199a/snap/snap-store/common/.cache/gio-modules/libgiognutls.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Failed to load module: /home/n199a/snap/snap-store/common/.cache/gio-modules/libgiognutls.so
/home/n199a/snap/snap-store/common/.cache/gio-modules/libgiolibproxy.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Failed to load module: /home/n199a/snap/snap-store/common/.cache/gio-modules/libgiolibproxy.so
18:45:45:0099 Gtk Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
18:45:45:0100 Gtk Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
18:45:45:0130 Gs  enabled plugins: desktop-categories, fwupd, os-release, packagekit, packagekit-local, packagekit-offline, packagekit-proxy, packagekit-refine-repos, packagekit-refresh, packagekit-upgrade, packagekit-url-to-app, appstream, desktop-menu-path, hardcoded-blacklist, hardcoded-popular, modalias, odrs, packagekit-refine, rewrite-resource, packagekit-history, provenance, snap, systemd-updates, generic-updates, provenance-license, icons, key-colors, key-colors-metadata
18:45:45:0130 Gs  disabled plugins: dpkg, dummy, fedora-langpacks, fedora-pkgdb-collections, repos
18:45:45:0217 Gs  /etc/PackageKit/Vendor.conf file not found
18:45:45:0218 Gtk /snap/snap-store/467/gnome-platform/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gtk-3.0/3.0.0/immodules/im-ibus.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
18:45:45:0219 Gtk Loading IM context type 'ibus' failed
18:45:45:0489 Gtk Could not load a pixbuf from icon theme.
This may indicate that pixbuf loaders or the mime database could not be found.
**
Gtk:ERROR:../gtk/gtkiconhelper.c:494:ensure_surface_for_gicon: assertion failed (error == NULL): Failed to load /snap/snap-store/433/data-dir/icons/Yaru/16x16/status/image-missing.png: Unable to load image-loading module: /snap/snap-store/467/gnome-platform/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gdk-pixbuf-2.0/2.10.0/loaders/libpixbufloader-png.so: /snap/snap-store/467/gnome-platform/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gdk-pixbuf-2.0/2.10.0/loaders/libpixbufloader-png.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory (gdk-pixbuf-error-quark, 5)
Bail out! Gtk:ERROR:../gtk/gtkiconhelper.c:494:ensure_surface_for_gicon: assertion failed (error == NULL): Failed to load /snap/snap-store/433/data-dir/icons/Yaru/16x16/status/image-missing.png: Unable to load image-loading module: /snap/snap-store/467/gnome-platform/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gdk-pixbuf-2.0/2.10.0/loaders/libpixbufloader-png.so: /snap/snap-store/467/gnome-platform/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gdk-pixbuf-2.0/2.10.0/loaders/libpixbufloader-png.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory (gdk-pixbuf-error-quark, 5)
```

Answer (score 1):

How I fixed this problem:

1. Install `gnome-software`:

`$ sudo apt install gnome-software`

2. With `gnome-software` update `snap-store` (tab name - `Update`)

**PROFIT!**