# I can't open My Ubuntu Software in my ubuntu

Tags: virtualbox

I newly installed My Ubuntu on virtual machine and I wanted to install VS Code, Discord, etc. But when I open Ubuntu Software it shows window and closes.

Comment: Make sure the system is fully updated and try again. Open a terminal and run `sudo apt update && sudo apt full-upgrade`. Also please edit the question and post the Ubuntu release/version -and- the virtualization software you're using.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ubuntu Software doesn't open in Ubuntu 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1231932/ubuntu-software-doesnt-open-in-ubuntu-20-04)