# Ubuntu Software Stuck in Loading Screen Ubuntu 21.10

Tags: software-center

Recently, when trying to install Lightworks using the .deb file provided by lwks.com, the Ubuntu Software app will stay loading. I tried downloading another app, Dolphin Emulator, using Dolphin's .deb file provided by dolphin-emu.org and it stayed loading for that as well.
Does anyone have a fix for this?

Comment: You can use `dpkg -i <deb name>` in the directory where the `.deb` file is downloaded.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ubuntu Software doesn't open in Ubuntu 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1231932/ubuntu-software-doesnt-open-in-ubuntu-20-04)

Comment: Have you tried typing `sudo apt install` followed by a space and then dragging and dropping the deb file into the terminal and then pressing enter?

Comment: The solution provided by @Error404 worked for me