# Can't see my installed programs via Ubuntu Software launcher

Tags: software-installation, launcher, 22.04

I just updated my OS to Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS (Jellyfish). The system seems to be running nice, but whenever I open the Ubuntu Software launcher, I can't see the programs installed in my laptop. How could I fix that?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1231932/ubuntu-software-doesnt-open-in-ubuntu-20-04