# Ubuntu software center could not open

Tags: software-center

I am using Ubuntu 22.10, OS Type 64 bit. I could not open Ubuntu software. I tried many solutions but could not fix the issue. I need to fix the issue, please anyone help me.

I tried below solutions

```
$ killall gnome-software

$ sudo apt autoremove gnome-software

$ sudo apt install gnome-software
$ sudo apt clean
$ sudo apt update

$ sudo apt update
$ sudo apt upgrade
```

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Could you [edit] your question to include some of the solutions that you tried? It would be a terrible waste of your time for 5 people to offer 5 solutions that you've already done that did not work ...

Comment: 64-bit isn't very helpful; is the *arm64* or ARM 64bit?  *ppc64el* or PPC 64-bit? maybe even *amd64* or x86 64-bit, .....   Why not be specific with your details as currently we have almost none.

Comment: OS type 64 bit, Gnome version 43.1

Comment: 64-bit isn't specific... Ubuntu supports multiple architectures with numerous that are 64-bit.  64bit ARM for example, 64-bit PowerPC/PPC, 64-bit AMD64, ....    ie. there are many 64-bit hardware platforms, from raspberry PIs, traditional PCs, to powerful machines (*PPC64 the most powerful 64-bit of the ones I listed*)

Comment: which version better, please provide details

Comment: They are all ~equal; just run on different forms of hardware.  *arm64* runs on ARM cpus such as apple devices, many modern android phones & more, *amd64* runs on x86_64 machines (intel created the 32-bit x86, AMD created the 64-bit compatible version used today as IA64 by intel was incompatible & no-one used it; Linux dropped support years ago), *ppc64el* is the 64-bit version of PPC machines (old 32-bit devices using PPC were made by apple; but apple switched to *amd64* then later to *arm64*).  Different 64-bit CPUs from different companies

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ubuntu Software doesn't open in Ubuntu 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1231932/ubuntu-software-doesnt-open-in-ubuntu-20-04)

Comment: Can you run gnome-software in the terminal and post the output?

Comment: By any chance, did you change your python version?